# Displaying Array taken from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-state

This is my first React Program where the program will decide from given options for the user.
I have made 5 components which are namely:

1. Add Options
2. Display Options
3. Remove Options.
4. Header
   5 Main (parent component)

I am not able to take the data as an input let alone display it and then giving user a random option and remove all the options.

Like I have got the general Idea of how the program should work but I am not able to write it in code.

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Display from "./Display";
import Remove from "./Remove";
import Add from "./AddOption";

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: [],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header></Header>
        <Display data={this.state.arr} />
        <Add handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React from "react";

export default class Display extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props; 
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Entered Data:</h2>
        {data && data.length > 0 ? (
          <ul>
            {data.map((item, index) => (
              <li key={index}>{item}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ) : (
          <p>No data entered yet.</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React from "react";

export default class Add extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this);
  }
  handleAddOption(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let option = event.target.option.value;
    alert("You Entered: " + option);
    event.target.option.value = "";
    this.props.handleAddOption(option);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
          <>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add Option"></input>
            <button>Add</button>
          </>
        </form>
        {this.props.arrElement.map((val) => (
          <p key={val}>{val}</p>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React from "react";

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Description</h2>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `<Add handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption} />` - What's `handleAddOption`?

Comment: it is a function which will add the input given by user to the array

Comment: Can you share it?

Comment: Yes. Here is the Function: ```handleAddOption(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let option = event.target.option.value;
    alert("You Entered: " + option);
    event.target.option.value = "";
    this.props.handleAddOption(option);
  }```

Comment: Nah, that’s not the function. I’m asking about what `this.props.handleAddOption` is, aka the function you are passing into `Add`/using within that code you just sent me

Comment: It is the function call which invokes the handleAddoption function passed as property to the parent component

Comment: So what is `this.props.handleAddOption`, doing? Can you share th code for that function? I assume that’s the code where you’re trying to add to your array state?

Comment: It is a reference to a function that is passed as a prop from the parent component to the Add component. This function is expected to handle the addition of a new option to the parent component's state or some other relevant data structure.

Comment: So to display what the user enters you need to update your array state in `Main`. Since your problem is relating to not being able to show what the user has entered, you should share what you’ve done for that function in the parent to update your state. Or have you not written that function yet and is what you’ve shared with us some sort of template/starter code?

Comment: I have shared what I have done up until now. In the Display.js Code I hoped to display the data by concatenating the original array with user entered data. I am talking about this. Check the Display one. It is the second snippet of code

Comment: Ok, since you're doing `<Add handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption} />` in `Main`, you should have an `handleAddOption` in that component which will add elements to your state array... did you try to implement that logic? I'm also unclear on what `this.props.arrElement` is supposed to be in `Add`. That would imply you're passing an `arrElement` prop to `Add`, but you're not doing that (and I'm unclear about what that's supposed to be).

Comment: I did implement that logic in the addOption component. Now I am confused by your last but of the question

Comment: Do you understand what `this.props` represents in your `Add` component? It’ll have properties that you pass to it when you use it `<Add />`. You’re not passing `arrElement` so that will be `undefined` when you try and access it. Similarly, you’re doing `this.props.handleAddOption` which means you should be passing a `handleAddOption` to `<Add />` - which you _are_ doing, but the value you are passing (in `Main`) is `this.handleAddOption`, which is `undefined` since your `Main` component does not have a `handleAddOption` method.

Comment: Okay I will try and work something out now